# Debian installer only offering "standard system utilities"

Tags: debian

I am attempting to do an install of debian 9, however, when i get to select software to install, where I normally see a screen that says GNOME, Web Server, OpenSSH Server, etc... the only option is "standard system utilities"

any ideas on how I can get more software options for installation?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to do this at system installation time and not later when you have a running system?

Comment: You may have been downvoted because it is a little unclear what you are saying. What kind of install are you doing? Have you just come to a screen in the installation process headed "Software Selection"? It specifies Desktops and Servers and Standard System Utilities ... but you can go past this. Look at something like https://www.linuxtechi.com/debian-9-installation-guide-with-screenshots/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "full" Debian installation media is 3 DVDs, or about 12 GB.

See here: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/

Since this is quite inconvenient and an internet connection is pretty much ubiquitous, a more common installation media choice contains a significantly smaller set of packages. It only installs the base system and then establishes a connection to official Debian package repositories over the network. I guess you're using this type of installation media without a network connection.

If you finish the installation, note that you can request that screen again by running `tasksel` as root. If you have added more installation sources since the installation itself (e.g., an Internet connection), you will then see the other options that should have been available during the installation.

Comment: No, he's right - that screen is typically present even on a "single floppy to boot netinstall system".  Seems like the possible tasks for `tasksel` aren't loaded...